# layout has more than 80 views, bad performance?

Tags: java, android

I am making my new app but I get bad performance hint ... that is my content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.chemistry.arabian.periodictable.about_developer"
    android:background="#263238">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/element_desc"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        
       <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/qal_logo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="@drawable/qal_earth_logo"/>

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:background="@drawable/transition_logo"/>

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/lanth_logo"/>

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/acti_logo"/>

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:background="@drawable/weak_logo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6" />

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/semi_logo"/>

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nonmetals_logo"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:background="@drawable/halogen_logo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9" />

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nobel_logo"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/element_desc"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/h"
                    android:id="@+id/h"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/he"
                    android:id="@+id/he"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="17" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/li"
                    android:id="@+id/li"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/be"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/be"

                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/b"
                    android:id="@+id/b"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="12" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/c"
                    android:id="@+id/c"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="13" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/n"
                    android:id="@+id/n"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="14" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/o"
                    android:id="@+id/o"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="15" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/f"
                    android:id="@+id/f"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="16" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ne"
                    android:id="@+id/ne"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="17" />

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/na"
                    android:id="@+id/na"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/mg"
                    android:id="@+id/mg"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/al"
                    android:id="@+id/al"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="12" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/si"
                    android:id="@+id/si"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="13" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/p"
                    android:id="@+id/p"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="14" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/s"
                    android:id="@+id/s"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="15" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cl"
                    android:id="@+id/cl"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="16" />

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ar"
                    android:id="@+id/ar"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_column="17" />

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow


                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/k"
                    android:id="@+id/k"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ca"
                    android:id="@+id/ca"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/sc"
                    android:id="@+id/sc"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ti"
                    android:id="@+id/ti"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/v"
                    android:id="@+id/v"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/crom"
                    android:id="@+id/cr"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/mn"
                    android:id="@+id/mn"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/fe"
                    android:id="@+id/fe"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/co"
                    android:id="@+id/co"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ni"
                    android:id="@+id/ni"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cu"
                    android:id="@+id/cu"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/zn"
                    android:id="@+id/zn"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ga"
                    android:id="@+id/ga"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ge"
                    android:id="@+id/ge"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/as"
                    android:id="@+id/as"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/se"
                    android:id="@+id/se"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/br"
                    android:id="@+id/br"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/kr"
                    android:id="@+id/kr"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow

                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rb"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rb"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/sr"
                    android:id="@+id/sr"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/y"
                    android:id="@+id/y"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/zr"
                    android:id="@+id/zr"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/nb"
                    android:id="@+id/nb"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/mo"
                    android:id="@+id/mo"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/tc"
                    android:id="@+id/tc"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ru"
                    android:id="@+id/ru"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rh"
                    android:id="@+id/rh"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/pd"
                    android:id="@+id/pd"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ag"
                    android:id="@+id/ag"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cd"
                    android:id="@+id/cd"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/element_description"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/in"
                    android:id="@+id/in"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

please any help to get the layout being correct >... and this is an Image For the Layout

[image]

Comment: try recycler or grid view http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: please, tell me how to make the grid view like the table I used

Comment: Please take one of the many gridview examples from the internet that show pictures from resource. You have your pictures already as resource. Then come back if you have any problem.

Comment: How to set the position of every ImageView on the GridView ?